# C# delegate with pre-set parameters

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I need to do something similar with command pattern, but in terms of delegate or something similar.

It should look like this:

```
private MyFunc Method1() {
    MyFunc func;
    
    /*
        set all parameters to func
    */  
    
    return func;
}

private void Method2()
{
    var funcWithAllParameters = Method1();
    funcWithAllParameters.Invoke();
}

private MyFunc(a lot of parameters) {}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to encapsulate MyFunc inside a class? The parameters could be the data members of the class. This way you can control their values or give default ones

Comment: You can't both return a `MyFunc` delegate that has parameters and then call it without specifying those parameter values. Instead, return a different, parameterless, delegate that matches the return type of `MyFunc`, something like either `Action` (for `void`) or `Func<T>` for other return types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a lambda function, which supplies the parameters for and calls `MyFunc`. The result is an `Action` delegate, which has the signature `void ()`

```cs
private Action Method1() {
    return () => MyFunc(new Type1(), null);
}

private void Method2()
{
    var funcWithAllParameters = Method1();
    funcWithAllParameters.Invoke();
}

private void MyFunc(Type1 p1, Type2 p2)
{
    //
}
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OEPUOU)

Comment: I think currying is applying the parameters one by one. Like making func<int, int, int>) => func<int, func<int,int>>. As for the question use closures. Cf https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Closures#:~:text=To%20put%20it%20very%20simply,re%20going%20to%20be%20used.

Comment: Closure is when you pull in a value from outside the lambda. I'm not doing that here: the values are created within the lambda. You might be right about currying, not sure if it's used to do multiple arguments simultaneously

Comment: So when is new Type1() evaluated? I did not consider this thoughtfully. If it is evaluated on calling Method1 (which I assumed in the first place - probably incorrectly) then it is added in the closure. As for the argument I think it would be nessesary to put some value in the closure and not create a value lazily.

Comment: It is not. It is evaluated at runtime of the lambda, which is when you call `Method2`. A closure would be `var x1 = new Type1(); return () => MyFunc(x1, null);` then it would be evaluated during `Method1`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the values into a closure like so:

```
private Func<TResult> Method1()
     => () =>  MyFunc(/*a lot of parameters*/"param1", 12, ...);
```

Thus you could load the parameters in the closure and use the Function afterwards:

```
var func = Method1();
var result = func();
```

And of course you can also use the function as parameter for other functions:

```
private TResult SomeOtherMethod(Func<TResult> functionWithSetParameters)
    => functionWithSetParameters();
```